# What qualities are needed for becoming the President?

Tags: president, india

How to win presidential elections? Is it necessary to have fame? Does it require a PhD?

Comment: Just look at some presidents you know. Do all have a PhD? Are all famous? Anyway I fear that the question is a bit too broad. Maybe you want to narrow it down by providing more specific details into what you are interested in? Maybe a country or a part in time? Or you want to reformulate it as "what makes top politicians different from ordinary politicians"? This might also be a sociology question. Or do you maybe mean legal requirements? They differ from country to country.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Oh yeah qualities may differ from one President to other. I wanted to ask how to choose among candidates whom to give this honor and power.

Comment: So what you really want to ask is basically what makes a president a good president (presumably you want to choose a "good" president) and how to recognize this in advance. This is quite a different question. It may also be subjective because it depends on your definition of a "good" president. What do you value? Which election do you mean? We cannot make that decision for you, but we can give you information, if you tell us better what kind of information you want.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Actually yes, I want to ask what makes a good President. Good in ethics and leadership. How to prove these qualities to all?

Comment: You need that your party nominates you, and that they also win the election. India has about 1.5billion people but only one of them is president, so I believe, you come out better if you target becoming, for example, a lawyer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To build the own team, and lead this team to great success. It cannot be any President without the team behind but if your role in the team is only moderate, somebody else is going to be the President. If the team is not successful then just all fail.

Who is good in communication with people, may focus on they social skills, applying them inside the team. Others may focus on other stronger sides like good technical skills needed for the goal, or very wide social networks that can reach resources needed for the team. In any case they still must be able to attract, organize and lead to success they command as a whole.